Can I increase my number of trained skills if I increase my Intelligence modifier?
I am currently playing a Rogue who had a lower than average intelligence score at character creation. As our party is nearing 5th level, I was anticipating where I might put some of my attribute boosts towards and Intelligence is on the list.
If I do elect to increase my Intelligence modifier, will I retroactively become trained in additional skills since starting Rogues are trained in 7 skills plus their Intelligence modifier?

Historical note: While Dungeons and Dragons 3.5rd edition had a rule specifying that  no skill points were gained when your intelligence modifier increased, this rule was omitted from Pathfinder first edition, presumably intentionally.

@GMJoe I actually found that when doing some Google searches on this issue which was what made it extra weird that I couldn't come up with search terms that gave me the answer for 2e.

Yes
The rules for leveling up cover this situation (Player Core, pg. 29):

If an attribute boost increases your character's Intelligence modifier, they become trained in an additional skill and language.

There aren't any caveats to this, so it works whether you started at -1 Int or +3 or anywhere in-between.

I feel like I read that section of the rules 3 times and completely missed it every time (thanks ADHD).
